# limit function to run after spesifict time

Tags: javascript

```
var change= document.getElementById("change");
var color= document.getElementById("color");
var result=document.getElementById("result");

function changecolor(){
    change.addEventListener("click",randomColor());
}
function randomColor(){
  for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    var randomColor ='#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,6);
    color.style.background=randomColor;
    result.innerHTML="current color is"+randomColor;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9yu3tjm/

i have function like that to generate random color. each click will genereate random color. i want to show an alert if the function run 5 times. and the function will stop (cant be click). how to do that

Comment: keep a counter.

Comment: Example : https://jsfiddle.net/z9yu3tjm/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a global variable for example `count`

```
var count = 1;

function randomColor(){ 
   if(count >5){ 
      return;
   }  
  for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    var randomColor ='#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,6);
    color.style.background=randomColor;
    result.innerHTML="current color is"+randomColor;
  }
  count ++;


}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qbevnvjj/

Comment: other answer using return false, you using return. is it same?

Comment: Do you want to use return value if yes then it's useful to return something else blank return is sufficient.

Comment: sir would u like to look at my jsfiddle, it didnt work at the first click https://jsfiddle.net/z9yu3tjm/5/

Comment: This is happening because you are binding addEventListner inside the changecolor() that means first time click event is not present. If you just put the event listener outside of this function it will work fine

Updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z9yu3tjm/7/

Please select the answer if it works for you.

Comment: sorry sir,  i didnt see your update code on your  url.  is iit wrong url maybe?

Comment: Can you see it now:

Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/z9yu3tjm/7 .

Answer (score 0):

Only you have to use is counter variable.
https://jsfiddle.net/z9yu3tjm/1/
I have updated your code and here is JS code.

```
var change= document.getElementById("change");
var color= document.getElementById("color");
var result=document.getElementById("result");

function changecolor(){
    change.addEventListener("click",randomColor());
}
var i=0;
function randomColor(){
        if(i<5){
    i++;
    var randomColor ='#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,6);
    color.style.background=randomColor;
    result.innerHTML="current color is"+randomColor;
    }else{
    alert('5 times run...');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter to keep trank of number of clicks and once it is over the limit remove the on click attribute so the event is not fired anymore.

use `change.removeAttribute('onclick');` to remove click event.

Example Snippet:

```js
var change = document.getElementById("change");
var color = document.getElementById("color");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var max_number_times = 5;
var number_of_times = 0;

function changecolor() {
  change.addEventListener("click", randomColor());
}

function randomColor() {
  if (number_of_times < max_number_times) {
    number_of_times++;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      var randomColor = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 6);
      color.style.background = randomColor;
      result.innerHTML = "current color is" + randomColor;
    }
  } else {
    alert("5 times done")
    change.removeAttribute('onclick');
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="change" onclick="changecolor()">change color</button>
<section id="color">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, ullam ex totam dolorem cupiditate! Velit autem, obcaecati magni molestiae architecto.</p>
  <p id="result"></p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **an architecture's concern** , We recommend to not modify `randomColor` function, however, to add another function which monitors `randomColor` calls.

```
function changecolor(){
    change.addEventListener("click",monitor);
}

randomColor.calls = 0; 

function monitor () {
  randomColor.calls ++;  
  randomColor.calls <=5 && randomColor(...arguments);
}
```

Just for code elegance :)